# Google Place Autocomplete API returning wrong place id

Tags: api, autocomplete

Since today (or yesterday) the Google Place Autocomplete web service (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) is returning a wrong place id (place_id). Does anyone know how to get the right place id from the Autocomplete API?

For example, the place id for New York City is `ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g` (according to the Place Details API), but the Autocomplete API returns `ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8iaBilOZXcgWW9yayBDaXR5LCBOZXcgWW9yaywgVmVyZW5pZ2RlIFN0YXRlbg` as place_id. The beginning of the string is almost the same, except for the last character of the 'right' place id (g).

Is this a bug or is Google changing their place ids? Unfortunately I can't find anything related to this problem.

Comment: Hi Kaas, I have been seeing the same issues today. Thankfully we have a fallback method if the place ID fails. This is something that we should raise with Google via their bug tracker. 

I will also be speaking with Google support over this today.

Answer (score 0):

Some place ids from the Place Autocomplete API have been altered due to a recent issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11107. The longer place ids should be accepted by all Maps APIs (but see the caveat in https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11107#c30).

Unfortunately, this will be around for some time. A way to get the "short" place id corresponding to a long one is to issue a Place Details call with the long place id (the returned result will have a short place id).